# Droidbox:Collected 0 sandbox logs?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, android-virtual-device

This error is that :

> 06:56:28 E/Device: Error during Sync: Local path doesn't exist

I can't solve it. And I have already ran droidbox long time,but it always display "Collected 0 sandbox logs".

The following is the specific content.

```
sue@ubuntu:~/DroidBox_4.1.1$ ./droidbox.sh kugou.apk

 ____                        __  ____
/\  _`\               __    /\ \/\  _`\
\ \ \/\ \  _ __  ___ /\_\   \_\ \ \ \L\ \   ___   __  _
 \ \ \ \ \/\`'__\ __`\/\ \  /'_` \ \  _ <' / __`\/\ \/'\
  \ \ \_\ \ \ \/\ \L\ \ \ \/\ \L\ \ \ \L\ \ \L\ \/>  </
   \ \____/\ \_\ \____/\ \_\ \___,_\ \____/ \____//\_/\_\
    \/___/  \/_/\/___/  \/_/\/__,_ /\/___/ \/___/ \//\/_/
Waiting for the device...
Installing the application kugou.apk...
06:56:28 E/Device: Error during Sync: Local path doesn't exist.
Running the component com.kugou.android/
              com.kugou.android.app.splash.SplashActivity...
Starting the activity 
              com.kugou.android.app.splash.SplashActivity...
Application started
Analyzing the application during infinite time seconds...
[\]Collected 0 sandbox logs   (Ctrl-C to view logs)ogs)
```

Comment: `path doesn't exist. `

Comment: What does this means? Do you know how to solve it?